# How to handle _rev id in cloudantdb bluemix, it's changing for every update?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, node-red

Consider I'm send record to mqtt subscriber from device. The data which I send it need to be stored in cloudant db.

For example if I'm sending `{"_id":45,"dob":1205}` it will be stored in cloudantdb with _rev id. If I need to update `_id:45` I need to include _rev id which is long and alpha numeric.

So in node red is there any other way to dynamically take the _rev id and to update the document?

Comment: You need to include more information in your question, show exactly what you already have and what you have already tried

Comment: Edit the question, don't use comments to add information

Comment: Updated the  question

Answer (score 2):

In order to update any document in Cloudant / CouchDB, you need both the _id and the most recent _rev value of that document.

That is, in order to update a doc with _id = 123, you'll have to first
`GET  database/123`, which will return the JSON doc like so

```
{
  _id:123,
  _rev:1-abcdefg,
  somekey : somedata
}
```

Then you change the doc however you like.

```
{
  _id:123,
  _rev:1-abcdefg,
  somekey : somedata,
  newkey : newdata
}
```

The `PUT database/123`.

Then, when you `GET database/123`, you should get something like

```
{
  _id:123,
  _rev:2-gfedbca,
  somekey : somedata,
  newkey : newdata
}
```

You'll see that the `_rev` value has changed to reflect the change in the document.

If you want to update the doc again, make sure to include the latest _rev value.

This means that in order to update a document in Cloudant/CouchDB, you must first GET that document (at least the _id and _rev), modify the data locally, then PUT it back on to the database.

Here's some documentation that should help: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/intro/api.html#revisions

(Note, if you use an old _rev in subsequent updates, you'll start to create conflicts within your database, resulting in a wide revision tree for your docs, eventually degrading the database performance.)